# How to compress PDF file using sevenzipsharper in c#?

Tags: c#, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I can compress a directory using the following code:

```
string dll = @"D:\7z.dll";
string source = @"D:\sample";
string output = @"D:\My7zipped.7z";
SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath(dll);
SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.ZipEncryptionMethod = ZipEncryptionMethod.Aes256;
compressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma2;
compressor.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Normal;
compressor.CompressDirectory(source, output);
```

But i want to compress into a single PDF file. How can I compress into a single PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SevenZipCompressor.CompressFiles` method instead of `SevenZipCompressor.CompressDirectory`.

Please try to find out the basics (like this) yourself. You are supposed to do some work on your own before asking here.

Comment: I have tried this SevenZipCompressor.CompressFiles. but i won't make sense to me.

Comment: That's too bad. But I can't help you with that. If you give it a try and get stuck, come here and ask a solid question including your best try.

Answer (score 0):

SevenZipCompressor tmp = new SevenZipCompressor();
tmp.CompressStream(File.OpenRead(sourceFile), File.Create(destinationFile));

There is an example on CodeProject of someone creating a C# interface for 7z using the SDK.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27148/C-NET-Interface-for-7-Zip-Archive-DLLs